# What is the name of this content-loading technique?

Tags: design-patterns, loading, user-experience

What is the name of this technique where (generally gray) containers, in the format of expected content, are shown while the content itself is being loaded?

[image: Gray containers while content being loaded]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is skeleton loader. You can use [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Skeleton-Loading-Screen-jQuery-avnSkeleton.html) plugin if you are using jQuery